# Need help with Rules of Identity for First Order Logic with Equality

Tags: logic

I'm a beginner in logic and I'm studying with textbooks. Right now I've just got to predicate logic with identity and I need to ask a few questions, so I can free my mind of doubts and sleep well at night.

Do the identity rules (Id)

p//x=x (reflexivity);

x=y ⇔ y=x (symmetry);

x=y/y=z//x=z (transitivity);

Fx/x=y//Fy, Fx/¬Fy//¬(x=y) (substitution);

apply to both variables and constants?

I'm almost certain that they do, but there's this textbook that says they only apply to constants, and then a more recent edition of the same book says it apply to both variables and constants. So I just need to be sure.

Another question:

If I have

1. Raa
2. ¬Rab

can I infer from both premises the line ¬(a=b) with the Id rules, or do I need some intermediate step? Or is it just wrong?

One last question: when doing Existential Instantiation (EI), I know I can replace the variable with a new constant, one that did not appear in the proof in any preceding line and in the conclusion line, and then drop the quantifier; but there's a textbook that says I could instantiate with a variable, providing it's a new one that has not been used, so this mean I can do EI with both variables and constants? I was sure that I could only instantiate with a constant, and that the constant was supposed to be a "temporary name". Can anyone clear this to me?

Answer (score 1):

The [quantifiers rules](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA177) can be more generally specified with *terms*.

Terms are : *variables*, *contants* or "complex" ones (like e.g. **x+0** in arithmetic).

The reason why is that every first-order theory has an ulimited supply of variables, while constants are usually few : one or none.

If we consider [first-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic), we have only one constant : **0**.

Thus, if we restrict the rules for quantifiers to constants, we are in trouble with e.g. the "instantiation" of the true sentence : **∃x (x ≠ 0)**.

---

Also the [equality rules](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA121) can be specified with terms :

> **(=I)** : we may derive **(t = t)** with no assumptions
>
> **(=E)** : if **φ** is a formula, **s** and **t** are terms substitutable for **x** in **φ**, and we have derivations **D** of **(s = t)** and **D'** of **φ[s/x]**, we may derive **φ[t/x]**. The undischarged assumptions are those of **D** together with those of **D'**.

---

With the rule :

> from **Fx** and **¬Fy**, derive : **¬(x=y)**,

you can apply it with **Rax** as **Fx**.

Thus, **Raa** is **Fa** and **¬Rab** is **¬Fb** and you can conclude with :

> **¬(a=b)**.